# Virtualbox fails to start VMs after update

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, software-center

After removing the version of virtualbox from the Software Center (5.0), I installed virtualbox-5.1 from the oracle repository. It seems that the kernal moduals from the version from the Software Center are conflicting with the new ones. The error messsage is:[image: Error Message]

What I have tried:

1. Running `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` and restarting. This outputs `vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules. vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.`
2. Reinstalling the Software Center version and purging it via the command line, and then reinstalling the version from oracle.
3. `dkms autoinstall`

Output of `dpkg -l *virtualbox*`:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  unity-scope-vi 0.1+13.10.20 all          VirtualBox scope for Unity
un  virtualbox     <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  virtualbox-5.1 5.1.12-11244 amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox
ri  virtualbox-dkm 5.0.24-dfsg- all          x86 virtualization solution - ker
un  virtualbox-gue <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-gue <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-mod <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-ose <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg -l *virtualbox*`? Please edit your answer to include that output. Start new comments with `@heynnema` if you need my attention, or I may miss the comment.

Comment: @heynnema The output has been added.

Comment: You need to `sudo dpkg -P virtualbox-dkms` and `sudo dpkg -P virtualbox-5.1` and then reinstall virtualbox-5.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After requesting a `dpkg -l *virtualbox*` and reviewing it, it's obvious that an old version of the virtualbox-dkms is installed.

```
ii  virtualbox-5.1 5.1.12-11244 amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox
ri  virtualbox-dkm 5.0.24-dfsg- all          x86 virtualization solution - ker
```

To solve the problem, you need to:

```
sudo dpkg -P virtualbox-dkms
sudo dpkg -P virtualbox-5.1
```

and then **reinstall virtualbox-5.1 and the extensions pack**.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 18.04, after I updated the kernel this issue showed up.
Download the .deb file from Virtualbox site, dont install the one in ubuntu software centre, i think they dont update the latest version there.

Download and install the .deb file. This resolved my problem.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The error message is misleading. Use this command:

```
sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup
```

to rebuild and install the kernel modules.

Comment: This gives the same output as `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` with the same result.

Comment: So you have something else broken :-(. I suggest you edit file /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh (as root) and set the first line to `#!/bin/sh -x`. Save it and try again. You will see exactly what that script is doing and hopefully you will find out what is wrong.

Comment: @sмurf see my answer